# Mapping array with objects of open hours in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

So Im trying to render in jsx a list of 7 days with open hours, taking data from my json file.
I want to make it looks somehow like this:

Mon
09:00 - 21:00

Tue
09:00 - 21:00

Wed
09:00 - 21:00

Thu
09:00 - 21:00

Fri
09:00 - 21:00

Sat 11:00 - 21:00

Sun
11:00 - 21:00

In my json file it looks like this:

```
openHours: [
          { days: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], from: '09:00', to: '21:00' },
          { days: [6, 0], from: '11:00', to: '21:00' },
        ],
```

So i tried to map openHours, got 2 objects, but when I try to map those 2 objects I get error that map is not a function. I wanted it to map in this way, that in this case, it returns 5 items with 09:00-21:00 and 2 items 11:00-21:00, but there can be case, that openHours will containt 3 objects, like days 1-5, day 6 and day 0. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over `openHours` and then, within that loop, iterate over `days`.

```js
function App() {
  const DAY_LOOKUP = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

  const openHours = [
    { days: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], from: '09:00', to: '21:00' },
    { days: [6, 0], from: '11:00', to: '21:00' },
  ]
  
  return openHours.map(group => {
    return group.days.map(day => (
      <p key={day}>{DAY_LOOKUP[day]} {group.from} - {group.to}</p>
    ))
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const openingHours = [
    { days: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], from: '09:00', to: '21:00' },
    { days: [6, 0], from: '11:00', to: '21:00' },
  ];

  const numberToDay = (number) => {
    switch(number) {
      default: return 'Monday';
      case 1:  return 'Tuesday';
      case 2:  return 'Wednesday';
      case 3:  return 'Thursday';
      case 4:  return 'Friday';
      case 5:  return 'Saturday';
      case 6:  return 'Sunday';
    }
  };

  const rows = openingHours.map((element, index) => {
    // Iterate over the days and return their appropriate string value
    const days = element.days.map((item) => {
      return numberToDay(item);
    });

    // Return new table row elements, while setting the key
    return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{days.join()}</td>
      <td>{element.from}</td>
      <td>{element.to}</td>
    </tr>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Days</th>
              <th>From</th>
              <th>To</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {rows}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-tdd-or9lf?file=/src/App.js

Do note that it is very important to set the `key` attribute when returning elements inside a loop to help React and the Virtual DOM in terms of optimizations.

For more information, please take a look at the React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html